# "Permission Denied" when creating a folder in tmp directory

Tags: linux, bash

I'm creating a script that counts the number of directories and files. I'm trying to create a new file in the tmp folder where it keeps track of how many directories there are by inserting a new line in that new file. However when I run the script I get a permission denied 'find /tmp/dcount'.

I have r,w,x permission in this directory and am the owner of all the files/directories too.

```
#!/bin/bash

find $1 \( -type d -fprintf /tmp/dcount "\n" \) ,\( -type f -fprintf /tmp/fcount"\n" \)
dirCount=(wc -l /tmp/dcount| cut -d" " -f1)
fileCount=(wc -l /tmp/fcount| cut -d" " -f1)
printf "Directory Count %d" dirCount
printf "File Count %d" fileCount
```

Comment: Please give an example of running your script from the command line.  What argument are you giving your script (for the `$1`)?

Answer (score 1):

Your `find` command line is not paying close enough attention to spacing.  You have:

```
find $1 \( -type d -fprintf /tmp/dcount "\n" \) ,\( -type f -fprintf /tmp/fcount"\n" \)
```

You need a space after the `,` and another before the second `"\n"`, and you should use double quotes around `$1`:

```
find "$1" \( -type d -fprintf /tmp/dcount "\n" \) , \( -type f -fprintf /tmp/fcount "\n" \)
```

However, GNU `find` rejects the original command with various errors — you really need to post exact copies of what you're executing (copy'n'paste is invaluable).  Do not risk retyping it — you'll make silly mistakes that make it look as if you're careless.

You also don't need the `\(` or `\)` operands:

```
find "$1" -type d -fprintf /tmp/dcount "\n" , -type f -fprintf /tmp/fcount "\n"
```

Now you need to decide whether messing with temporary file names is a good idea.  You could simply write:

```
echo "Directory Count $(find "$1" -type d -print | wc -l)"
echo "File Count $(find "$1" -type f -print | wc -l)"
```

Since there are no temporary files, there are (a) no file permission problems writing to such files and (b) you don't have to remove them when the script completes (or is terminated by an interrupt).

The only downside to this is that there are two scans over the directory hierarchy under `"$1"`.

Note that if you must keep the file names, you should at minimum use `.$$` in the names: `-fprintf /tmp/dcount.$$` to ensure that concurrent executions of the program don't interfere with each other.  For security (non-predictable names), you should use:

```
dcount=$(mktemp /tmp/dcount.XXXXXX)
fcount=$(mktemp /tmp/fcount.XXXXXX)
trap "rm -f $dcount $fcount; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

find "$1" -type d -fprintf "$dcount" "\n" , -type f -fprintf "$fcount" "\n"

echo "Directory Count" $(wc -l <"$dcount")
echo "File Count" $(wc -l <"$fcount")

rm -f "$dcount" "$fcount"
trap 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The permissions error is probably because you are trying to search a directory that you don't have access to.  Your use of `/tmp` should not be generating any permissions errors.

In any case, this script can be simplified.  There is no need to write temporary output files to `/tmp`.  Here's one simpler version:

```
#!/bin/bash

 dirCount=$(find $1 -type d | wc -l)
 fileCount=$(find $1 -type f | wc -l)
 echo Directory Count: $dirCount
 echo File Count: $fileCount
```

If this was stored in a script file called `countstuff`, for example, and your home directory was `/home/alice`, for example, then you could run this script like this:

```
 countstuff /home/alice
```

If you didn't need the results stored in variables, but just wanted to display the results, then this script could be shortened further:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Directory Count: $(find $1 -type d | wc -l)
echo File Count: $(find $1 -type f | wc -l)
```